# Blurry objects on material preview viewport mode

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image]Suddenly every objects look blurry when I enter the material previwe mode.
I tried reset the pixel filter value, but it doesn't work.

Please help me to figure it out why, and how to fix it !
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? Upload and copy paste the URL it will generate: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Does it happen in a new default blend file?